# How to get an online database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I wondered what's the best way to get an online database. I have a localhost/phpmyadmin db, but it only works on my computer. Is it any way to get it online?

Answer (score 3):

You need a server(host) which supports databases. Usually the admin-part of that host will have a database interface; Otherwise you can upload phpmyadmin to that server via FTP(Filezilla)